# HTML5 Page Structure: Section and Article correct placement

Tags: html, structure, sections

I'm trying to build correct structure for HTML Page.
My question is about `article` and `section` tags implementation. 
`article` tag inside `section` tag or `section` tag inside `article` tag. Which one should be correct? 


*Here is my structure*
[image: Here is my structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. It depends on the incident you are going to apply it.

Read below links to understand it's usage,

Article - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp

Section - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp

Cheers !!!

Answer (score 3):

This article contains some useful information:

https://iandevlin.com/blog/2011/04/html5/html5-section-or-article/

There's no reason you can't have a section, in an article, which is itself inside a section, so long as that best describes the content on which you're working.